# Instruments > Automation > logging

Tags: xcode, instruments, ui-automation

Is it possible to log output from the **UIAutomation** tool in Instruments?

e.g. while running a script `console.log()` does not seem to output anything.

Comment: don't expect any of the javascript objects you're used to in a browser such as the console and the document objects to be available in your automation scripts, only the things in the framework reference will be there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
UIALogger.logDebug();
```

More information here: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIALoggerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009906)